# How to Handle State Taxes Between MI and FL?

Tags: united-states, taxes, state-income-tax, michigan

Two scenarios:

Let's say I earn 50k...

1. Primary residence is Michigan (8 months) / Secondary residence is Florida (4 months).
   I work remotely for a company in Texas which doesn't take out state taxes.
   How do I handle state taxes?
2. Primary residence is Florida (6 months and 4 days) / Secondary residence is Michigan (6 months and 1 day).
   I work remotely for a company in Texas which doesn't take out state taxes.
   How do I handle state taxes?

Please provide specific calculations and amounts for each scenario as well steps to file taxes.

Answer (score 3):

In both cases, you pay Michigan taxes for the whole year. See the [instructions](http://www.michigan.gov/documents/taxes/MI-1040_book_Instructions_477624_7.pdf#Page=6):

> A  temporary  absence  from  Michigan,  such  as  spending  the 
>   winter  in  a  southern state, does  not  make you a part-year
>   resident

From the pattern in both of your scenarios, I think it will be hard to claim that you're not a Michigan tax resident. You can end up being resident in more than one State for tax purposes, but in your case the other State (Florida) doesn't have personal income tax, so it's not a problem.

For specifics on how to calculate the tax and how to file the tax return - read the instructions I linked to.